# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement' ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reference

I am trying to reference data into reactJS along with typescript. While doing this I am getting below error

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'
```

Please let me know what exactly incorrect here, I used documentaiton from React
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
but I think I am doing something wrong here.
Below is the scope snippet

```
  class Results extends React.Component<{}, any> {
  private textInput: HTMLInputElement;
  .......
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { topics: [], isLoading: false };

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    }

     componentDidMount() {.....}

    handleLogin() {
    this.textInput.focus();
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(this.textInput.value);
   .......
}

  render() {
    const {topics, isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
              <input ref={(thisInput) => {this.textInput = thisInput}} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
              <div className="input-group-btn">     
                           <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={this.handleLogin}>

   ...............
```

Any idea what I may be missing here?

Comment: is it happening only when you are changing the route, i mean when unmounting the component?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes.

Comment: also just write as follows:
private textInput: HTMLInputElement | null;

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The error is produced becase the types definitions says input can be `null` or a `HTMLInputElement`

You can set `"strict": false` in your `tsconfig.json`

Or you can force the input to be `HTMLInputElement` type

```
<input ref={thisInput => (this.textInput = thisInput as HTMLInputElement)} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
```

This way is also valid ([using definite assignment assertions (typescript >= 2.7)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions))

```
<input ref={thisInput => (this.textInput = thisInput!)} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I used the approach "thisInput as HTMLElement" bur now it gives another error. Saying .." Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'"

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was an `HTMLInputElement`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Just pointing out the typo in example. `HTMLEInputlement` should be `HTMLInputElement`. @lleon

Answer (score 13):

This is, indeed, caused by you correct and commendable use of:

```
"strict": "true"
```

Which sets a few rules including the all important:

"strictNullChecks": "true"

## Handling Potential Nulls

The correct way to handle this is to check that the element isn't in fact null, because almost every method you use to query an element may fail to find one.

In the example below, the if-statement acts as a type guard, so the type of `HTMLElement | null` is narrowed to just `HTMLElement`.

```
const elem = document.getElementById('test');

if (elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = 'Type here is HTMLElement, not null';
}
```

## Handling HTML Element Types

To narrow the type from `HTMLElement` to `HTMLInputElement`, you can take an "I know better" approach and use a type assertion (making a class of subtle errors possible):

```
const example = <HTMLInputElement> elem;
```

Or you can use a custom type guard to do it properly, the below example takes `HTMLElement | null` and narrows it to `HTMLInputElement` if it isn't null, and has the correct tag name:

```
function isInputElement(elem: HTMLElement | null): elem is HTMLInputElement {
  if (!elem) {
    // null
    return false;
  }

  return (elem.tagName === 'INPUT')
}
```

The updated type guard call looks like this:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('test');

if (isInputElement(elem)) {
  console.log(elem.value);
}
```

Comment: "commendable" ... personally i think its a mugs game +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

I solved in react using if condition before i use ref

```
  if (this.ref.current) {

      this.editor = monaco.editor.create(
          this.ref.current,
          { automaticLayout: true }
      );

      monaco.editor.setTheme('vs-dark');
      this.editor.setModel(this.model);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution that I Found while googling which convincing enough to make this issue resolved.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the original source and more explanation on why this approach could be useful.

Comment: Why code images?