# null cannot be assigned to type

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript project, I've created a custom class (inspired by Rust's `Result<T, E>`, incidentally) and it looks like this:

```
export class Result<T, E extends Error = Error>
{
    public errors: E[] = [];
    public result: T | null = null;

    public static ok<T, E extends Error>(result: T): Result<T, E>
    {
        return new Result(result, [] as E[]);
    }

    public static err<T, E extends Error>(...errors: E[]): Result<T, E>
    {
        return new Result<T, E>(null as unknown as T, errors);
    }

    public static apiErr<T>(...errors: ApiErrorKind[]): Result<T, ApiError>
    {
        return new Result<T, ApiError>(null as unknown as T, errors.map(e => new ApiError(e)));
    }

    private constructor(result: T | null, errors: E[])
    {
        this.result = result;
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public and<T2, E2 extends Error = E>(f: (x: T) => Result<T2, E2>): Result<T2, E | E2>
    {
        if (this.isErr)
            return Result.err(...this.errors);

        let errors: (E | E2)[] = this.errors;

        try
        {
            return f(this.result as T);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            errors.push(e as E2);
        }

        return Result.err(...errors);
    }

    // irrelevant methods omitted for brevity

    public then<T2, E2 extends Error = E>(f: (x: T | null) => T2): Result<T2, E | E2>
    {
        if (this.isErr)
            return Result.err(...this.errors);

        let errors: (E | E2)[] = this.errors;

        try
        {
            return Result.ok(f(this.result));
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            errors.push(e as E2);
        }

        return Result.err(...errors);
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to use it, I keep getting mysterious errors about null casting, despite not having any `null` in sight:

```
export async function createUser(input: UserInput, organization: string): Promise<Result<User, ApiError>>
{
    const validation = validateUser(input); // returns Result<boolean, ApiError>

    if (validation.isErr)
        return Result.err<User, ApiError>(... validation.errors); // Error on this line
}
```

> **TS2322** Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'Result'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Result'.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: I ran your code example on my local machine and did not see the error you are experiencing.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin 3.3.3333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "Type 'string | null' is not assignable ..." when getting Item from LocalStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55667235/90527)

Answer (score 1):

You can set "strictNullChecks": false in compilerOptions of your tsconfig.json.

For more details, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488701/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-htmlinputelement-reactjs) answer, and [this](https://ariya.io/2016/10/typescript-2-and-strict-null-checking) link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the fact that I had placed a `then` method on my `Result<T, E>` type. This created a conflict when I tried to return the type from an `async` method because TypeScript kept assuming that my `Result<T, E>` was a pseudo-`Promise` and trying to unwrap it by calling `.then()`.

TypeScript normally has a much clearer error for this type of situation:

> **TS1058** The return type of an async function must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.

But it gets much more muddled up once the method accepts a function as an argument, since that's what an actual `Promise`'s method signature looks like, and it becomes even more confusing with generics involved.