# Error: "Type 'string | null' is not assignable ..." when getting Item from LocalStorage

Tags: typescript, eslint, tslint

As I understand that I cannot assign null to a string variable. I do not understand why the if clause to check that `localStorage.getItem('language')` is set isnt resolving this issue.

Error: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
  setLanguage(lang: string) {
    if (lang) {
      this.language = i18n.locale = lang
      localStorage.setItem('language', lang)
    } else {
      if (localStorage.getItem('language')) {
        this.language = i18n.locale = localStorage.getItem('language')
      } else {
        let browserLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0]
        this.language = i18n.locale = browserLang
        localStorage.setItem('language', browserLang)
      }
    }
  }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it stems from the fact that you are not assigning it to a variable. The first time and second time you call `localStorage.getItem('language')` might return different result (as far as the typescript compiler is concerned).
You might want to try something like:

```
  setLanguage(lang: string) {
    if (lang) {
      this.language = i18n.locale = lang
      localStorage.setItem('language', lang)
    } else {
      const lang: string | null = localStorage.getItem('language'); // Notice how I'm setting a new variable here
      if (lang) {
        this.language = i18n.locale = lang;
      } else {
        let browserLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0]
        this.language = i18n.locale = browserLang
        localStorage.setItem('language', browserLang)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that localStorage return `string | null` and isTokenExpired() helper method of jwt takes only `string | undefine`. value. so you can do something like this.
Check if the value is null or not before passing it. Or, if it is null change it’s value to undefined

```
const lan= localStorage.getItem('language');

if (language)
  this.language = i18n.locale = lang;
```