# TypeScript problems with functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have such code:

```
   export class Board implements IBoard {
      choosedPiece = false;
    
      constructor() {
        this.clicked();
      }
   }
```

and functions like this:

```
    public pieceOnClick(target: EventTarget): void {
        if (this.choosedPiece) {
          const clickedPiece = this.findPiecePosition((target as HTMLDivElement));
    
          if (clickedPiece.instance !== null) {
            this.choosedPiece = false;
            this.clickedEl(target);
          }
        }
      }
    
    
  clicked(): void {
    this.chessBoard.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
      if(!this.clickedEl(target)){
        this.clickPiece(target);
      }
    })
  }
```

And now I have such an error  Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventTarget'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget'.

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some possibilities to get `null` instead of `EventTarget` on the `target` variable. Just add one condition to eliminate `null`

```
this.chessBoard.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if(target && !this.clickedEl(target)){ // This block will be executed if target is not null
        this.clickPiece(target);
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks, now it works, but i have same error for clickedEl

Answer (score 4):

The error comes because not all event `target` is of the type `HTML Element`. Other possible types can be `XMLHttpRequest`, `FileReader`, `AudioNode`, `AudioContext`, etc.

To fix this error you need to tell TypeScript the type. One way is following.

```
clicked(): void {
    this.chessBoard.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        const target = event.target as Element;
        if (!this.clickedEl(target)) {
            // this.clickPiece(target);
        }
    });
}
```

References:

1. [How to Fix "Property '...' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'" TypeScript Error?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-property-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-typescript-error)
2. [Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement' ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488701/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-htmlinputelement-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

According to the TypeScript typings for DOM, the [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property can be `null`. Therefore, you can first check if the target exists:

```js
this.chessBoard.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    if (target && !this.clickedEl(target)) {
        this.clickPiece(target);
    }
});
```

I do remember it being `null` (or `undefined`) once, when adding certain mobile APIs in the mix, but otherwise it's always been defined. But to be sure, a simple check is fine, which also causes TypeScript to accept it due to [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).